# Subquery returned more than one value. this is not permitted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pull data from different tables and trying to get golivedata based on date and customer id. Below is query.

```
select c.customerID,  
       c.CustomerName,  
       cs.ContactName, 
       e.ComponentName, 
       e.ComponentVersion, 
       (
           select ps.GoLiveDate  
           from   Projects ps 
           where  ps.GoLiveDate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
           and    ps.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
       ) as CurrentGoLiveDate 
from   projects p 
       join customers c    on c.CustomerID = p.CustomerID 
       join contacts cs    on cs.ProjectID = p.ProjectID 
       join Environments e on e.ProjectID  = p.ProjectID 
where  e.ComponentName like 'RP%' 
and    cs.ContactType = 'Account Manager'
```

But I am getting an error:

[image: error image]

Comment: you are trying to get the `GoLiveDate` by customer ? For customer with multiple projects, that sub-query will returns multiple rows. Which `GoLiveDate` do you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery in the Select statement is returning more than one record.

```
WHERE ps.GoLiveDate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND ps.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

is matching more than one row. You either need to `SELECT TOP 1` or `SELECT MIN/MAX` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the result of your subquery as a value in your final `select` statement. Since the query returns more than one value, you get the error. If you expect more than one value out of the subquery you should design your query differently

Answer (score 0):

Expected results would have helped, you can make use of exists and get the value in that way. I am assuming you are looking for customers who have at least one row (if there are multiple rows with multiple go live dates for the same customers) with go live date less than current time stamp.

I think this may also help you to get your expected output.

```
select c.customerID,  c.CustomerName,  cs.ContactName, e.ComponentName, e.ComponentVersion,
  ps.GoLiveDate as CurrentGoLiveDate 
 from projects p 
 join customers c on c.CustomerID = p.CustomerID 
 join contacts cs on cs.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
 join Environments e on e.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
  where e.ComponentName like 'RP%' and cs.ContactType= 'Account Manager' 
  and exists (select 1 from Projects ps where  ps.GoLiveDate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ps.CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that in the image that you posted, there is a `TOP 1`. I am just guessing that you wanted the max `GoLiveDate`.

```
select c.customerID,  
       c.CustomerName,  
       cs.ContactName, 
       e.ComponentName, 
       e.ComponentVersion, 
       (
           select MAX(ps.GoLiveDate)   -- Added MAX() here
           from   Projects ps 
           where  ps.GoLiveDate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
           and    ps.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
       ) as CurrentGoLiveDate 
from   projects p 
       join customers c    on c.CustomerID = p.CustomerID 
       join contacts cs    on cs.ProjectID = p.ProjectID 
       join Environments e on e.ProjectID  = p.ProjectID 
where  e.ComponentName like 'RP%' 
and    cs.ContactType = 'Account Manager'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont worry about duplicate customer you can use this :

```
select c.customerID,  
       c.CustomerName,  
       cs.ContactName, 
       e.ComponentName, 
       e.ComponentVersion, 
       x.CurrentGoLiveDate
from   projects p 
       join customers c    on c.CustomerID = p.CustomerID 
       join contacts cs    on cs.ProjectID = p.ProjectID 
       join Environments e on e.ProjectID  = p.ProjectID 
       join (select ps.GoLiveDate  CurrentGoLiveDate, CustomerID
             from   Projects ps 
             where  ps.GoLiveDate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) as X on X.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
where  e.ComponentName like 'RP%' 
and    cs.ContactType = 'Account Manager'
```

in other cases you should use `TOP 1` or `MAX/MIN`